# Samba4 locked pst files

Tags: linux, samba, outlook, samba4

i have a samba4 server that holds my clients outlook pst files, if the outlook client or the machine crashes i must go to the server to kill the PID manually.

i saw there was "reset on zero vc =yes" parameter that can solve the problem but that is no longer supported in samba4 although it is in the man pages!!!?

any idea guys?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing PST files on a network share... especially using a non-Windows server.

Comment: @ewwhite my question is not about what i should or should not do, this is an existing situation.

Comment: great question! let me know when you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That setting does not do what you think it might, so not a problem it is gone.

It seems that Samba itself, because it is running the CIFS protocol, does not have a mechanism to differentiate between "client went away and is coming back" and "client just plain went away."  Which is why Samba will continue with the locks you are encountering after client machines crash, etc.

It appears some folks have had luck tweaking the socket-level timeouts for Samba, specifically SO_KEEPALIVE, to solve this problem:   http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/Auto-Removal-of-Straggling-File-locks-due-to-Ungraceful-Client-Disconnects-td3171543.html.